# Do I need to use iOS default controls in html?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, mobile

I'm building a cordova app, I'd rather not use the default popups such as the spinner that happens when you focus on a `<select></select>` (I'll make my own dropdown that works in mobile) and I want to build my own numpad when you focus on a textarea (which I'll make as a div that just pops up my own numpad), not use the ios keyboard. Basically, I don't want to use any of the native controls that popup. Instead I want to do it all in html.

Is there anything in the user experience guidelines that say I can't do this when submitting to app store?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is nothing that exactly permitts you to send such apps to the store. Apple has a Guideline for Developers/Designers. I would recommend you, to have a look into it. You can find it here: [Apple Design Guidelines - UI Elements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Controls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH15-SW1). But that doesn't say, that apple allows you that. Every App you submit to the store will be reviewed.

If apple permitts you to do it like you said (HTML/CSS) i would think about a native keyboard which fits your needs. Since iOS8 you are possible to build your "own" keyboard as you need it. But i don't know how to implement this into the cordova application. You could have a look over here for 16 Keyboards that were build for iOS8: [16 great iOS8 Keyboards](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/ios8-keyboards-confirmed/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom keyboard from application extension.

[image]

If you want to create custom keyboard try following link http://www.appcoda.com/custom-keyboard-tutorial/

**It is not necessary to use iOS controls.** 
if you really want to do it using HTML code so you need to create popup view using HTML tags and create id and class to handle the same using jQuery functions. try following link http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-keyboard-with-css-and-jquery--net-5774

Comment: I wanted to create a custom keyboard just for my html app not an ios 8 keyboard but tnx